# Create variants of products

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm looking for an **efficient way** to group different types of product variants.

I have this `json` file, and inside each product I have an different type of attributes.

```
Attributes: [

    {title: color, labels: [{title: red}, {title: blue}]},

    {title: brand, labels: [{title: nike}, {title: rebook}]},

    {title: size, labels: [{title: 38}, {title: 40}]

]
```

and it can have more/less attributes.

I need to create an efficient function that will return:

```
variants: [

    'red nike 38',

    'red nike 40',

    'blue nike 38',

    'blue nike 40',

    'red rebook 38',

    'red rebook 40',

    'blue rebook 38',

    'blue rebook 40'

]
```

Comment: At first sight the most efficient way will be some sort of loop on the JSON object, if you add the code you tried so far will be easier to help

Answer (score 1):

Since you have json file (from where the data is retreived), the attributes values should be either in `string` or `number` format.

Formatted the `data` as well.

Here is the solution:

```js
// input data
data = [{
        title: 'color',
        labels: [{
            title: 'red'
        }, {
            title: 'blue'
        }]
    },
    {
        title: 'brand',
        labels: [{
            title: 'nike'
        }, {
            title: 'rebook'
        }]
    },
    {
        title: 'size',
        labels: [{
            title: 38
        }, {
            title: 40
        }]
    }

]

// data modifier - to modify the data for the reducer method (will return array of array which contains value for each attribute)
function modifier(data) {
    return data.map(a => a.labels.map(b => b.title))
}

// reducer - to convert the data into desired format
function reducer(data) {
    return data.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), [])).map(i => i.join(' '))
}

// output - resultant data
output = reducer(modifier(data))
document.write(output)
```